# OpenLayers3: trigger ol.deselect upon select of another ol

Tags: openlayers-3

Right now I have ol.interaction.Select with a condition: ol.events.condition.click.  There are separate events that happen whether the event is selected or deselected.

However, what I want to do is upon selecting another feature, the previous feature selected is automatically deselected.  Is this possible?

Comment: ol,interaction.Select by default discards previously selected feature before the next click. See the below example <http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html?q=select>

Comment: Yep, I got it.  Thanks.